# LLVM build only selected tools or targets

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, dwarf

I am new to c++ & am referring to the llvm project https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html. There is a guide saying

```
If you are space-constrained, you can build only selected tools or only selected targets. The Release build requires considerably less space.
```

But I am unable to find the exact way to do it.

Currently, I am running the following to build all the tools

```
mkdir build
cmake ../llvm
make
```

This would create many tools such as llvm-addr2line, llvm-ar, llvm-dwarfdump etc.

1. How could I build it such that it only gives me 1 tool, eg llvm-dwarfdump (eg https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-dwarfdump.html)?
2. Is there an easy way to know the code that makes up these command.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

CMake generates a target for every `add_library`, `add_executable`, and `add_custom_target` command. These targets can be built separately by calling `make <target>` or with the build tool independent CMake abstraction `cmake --build <builddir> --target <targetname> --config Release`. To find out which targets have been defined by LLVM you need to inspect all CMakeLists.txt and *.cmake files.

Comment: Hm, there is `CMake Error: Unknown argument --target`. Any ideas?

Comment: How does your entire cmake command line looks like? I suspect a missing argument or empty environment variable before `--target` argument.

Comment: You're right. I need to use `cmake --build --target X86 --config Release`. However, in that case cmake quickly says `Built target X86` (i.e. w/o actually building modified C++ code). Any ideas why cmake cannot detect that C++ was modified?

Comment: The CMake call you used expects the build directory after `--build` command. So `cmake --build <build_dir> --target X86 --config Release` is what should work. There is also a second `--build` signature that expects `--preset <preset_name>` as argument, see [cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `.`. The command I've used is: `cmake --build . --target X86 --config Release`. And it quickly exists w/o actually building: `time cmake --build . --target X86` outputs `Built target X86` followed by `real    0m1.696s user    0m1.634s sys     0m0.061s`. Prior to building I did cleanup using `cmake --build . --target clean`. The `X86` is indeed listed as a target: `cmake --build . --target help | grep -P '... X86' -w` produces `... X86`. If I run `cmake --build .` it starts the build. Why the build is not started if `--target X86` is used?

Comment: I would recommend to start a new question as it does not fit the comment section of an answer and is easier for others to jump in and help you.

Comment: Re: "start a new question": [done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75172182/1778275).